# Global sanitation of user input in PHP

Tags: php

I recently came across a post in a forum, where it was asked about implementing global sanitation of super globals such as $_GET, $_POST and the rest BEFORE it even enters the database.

What do you guys think of this method, as i was thinking of implementing this, cause there may be a time where i forget to do the proper sanitation.

I am also looking for a free class before making my own, but the one i found was for PHP 3.0.

Will `array_walk_recursive` do the job for my purpose?

Answer (score 2):

There was actually already php functionality built to do exactly this in php called magic_quotes_gpc . If you set magic_quotes_gpc to on in your php.ini it will do this for you. However, for a lot of reasons(see [this blog post](http://aaroncameron.net/article.html?aID=59) for one guys write up of pros/cons) this was found to be a bad idea, and everyone turned it off and went back to quoting things as they went into the database by using a database abstraction layer for all database queries. Think PDO. Since you have no idea where adding extra quotes will help or hurt you, you could just turn on magic_quotes_gpc, but I don't recommend that. If the code base needs maintenance, do the maintenance the right way, and start pulling out your raw sql into calls using PDO.

Answer (score 2):

Don't touch the superglobals until it's time to actually use the data somewhere. e.g.... you don't know if you'll be inserting into a database, or outputting into an HTML page, or building some Javascript, or whatever.

As soon as you start mucking around with the superglobals' contents, you lose them as a source of "original" data, and start having to undo previously done work. That's one reason why PHP's auto-escaping of form data was a bad idea - it assumed you were dealing purely with a database and would never ever have to send the data elsewhere: database escaping is not the same as html escaping is not the same as javascript escaping is not the same as ... etc...

As well, if you're building a module or library for re-use elsewhere, you can't assume that whatever changes you make to the superglobals won't break things in other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you start messing about in the super globals, you'll run into trouble at one point or another. For example, what if you do actually want to store that piece of JavaScript in your database?

Personally, I think user input sanitation is a bad idea. What it usually means, is that you end up either throwing away data or polluting your database with a whole bunch of escape characters or XML/HTML character entities. That's just a bad way to handle data.

So what problems are we trying to avoid by sanitizing our user input? SQL injection? Use parameterized queries and be done with it. But what about code injection? Simple: sanitize your output! Apply htmlspecialchars() (and perhaps some other similar functions) to user data coming from the database (or any other source) and you've taken care of that problem while still keeping the original data intact. The added bonus is that you can adjust your sanitation process at any time and benefit from it not just for new data being entered, but also for all the existing data as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with applying sanitation globally is you're basically restricted to white-lists or black-lists of dangerous input or escaping. You can't easily implement type-checks at the global level since how will your application know what datatype the various inputs should be?

You'll be restricted for searching for dangerous input like "< script >" or "; Drop table", etc, or escaping all input which will not catch all vulnerabilities.

Also it is very easy to miss things in your whitelists, e.g. special encodings.

Comment: The reason i was asking is because a very good forym system called MyBB also applies this and just escapes stuff when doing SQL queries(my website is also MySQL driven)